# Wordpress Json api get google maps lat/lng from advanced custom fields

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I´m working on an App that is supported by the REST API from wordpress, I´m using ACF Pro and one of the fields prints a Google map, I need to retrieve the lat and lng from the json but I´m getting the following:

```
"ubicar": [
    "a:6:{s:7:\"address\";s:61:\"Retorno 205 7, Modelo, 09089 Ciudad de M\u00e9xico, D.F., M\u00e9xico\";s:3:\"lat\";s:18:\"19.362424484390957\";s:3:\"lng\";s:18:\"-99.12814199924469\";s:4:\"zoom\";s:2:\"18\";s:10:\"center_lat\";s:17:\"19.36230960838862\";s:10:\"center_lng\";s:18:\"-99.12727292005997\";}"
  ]
```

Right now I´m using the following code to get this:

```
var obj = json.post.custom_fields.ubicar;
```

and I can´t get the lat or lng values, I tried:

```
var obj = json.post.custom_fields.ubicar.lat;
```

Do you know what do I have to do to get those values with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Jquery's parseJSON function to process that ubicar array. See more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

So, you should be able to do the following

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json.post.custom_fields.ubicar);
```